# Error on NPM install - Phantomjs@1.9.18

Tags: npm, phantomjs, mean.io

Getting this every time I try to install mean.io application have tried 
        npm cache clean, 
        tried total reinstall , 
going mad at the moment . Am also running this as administrator. pleas help

```
    C:\Users\mmcelhinney\pitch_v1>npm install
    -
    > phantomjs@1.9.18 install C:\Users\mmcelhinney\pitch_v1\node_modules\phantomjs
    > node install.js

    Download already available at C:\Users\MMCELH~1\AppData\Local\Temp\phantomjs\phantomjs-1.9.8-windows.zip
    Extracting zip contents
    Removing C:\Users\mmcelhinney\pitch_v1\node_modules\phantomjs\lib\phantom
    Copying extracted folder C:\Users\MMCELH~1\AppData\Local\Temp\phantomjs\phantomjs-1.9.8-windows.zip-extract-1456238458670\phantomjs-1.9.8-windows -> C:\Users\mmcelhinney\pitch_v1\node_modules\phantom
    s\lib\phantom
    Phantom installation failed { [Error: EPERM, unlink 'C:\Users\MMCELH~1\AppData\Local\Temp\phantomjs\phantomjs-1.9.8-windows.zip-extract-1456238458670\phantomjs-1.9.8-windows\phantomjs.exe']
      errno: -4048,
      code: 'EPERM',
      path: 'C:\\Users\\MMCELH~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\phantomjs\\phantomjs-1.9.8-windows.zip-extract-1456238458670\\phantomjs-1.9.8-windows\\phantomjs.exe' } Error: EPERM, unlink 'C:\Users\MMCELH~1\App
    ata\Local\Temp\phantomjs\phantomjs-1.9.8-windows.zip-extract-1456238458670\phantomjs-1.9.8-windows\phantomjs.exe'
        at Error (native)
    npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.1.7601
    npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install"
    npm ERR! node v0.12.0
    npm ERR! npm  v2.5.1
    npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE

    npm ERR! phantomjs@1.9.18 install: `node install.js`
    npm ERR! Exit status 1
    npm ERR!
    npm ERR! Failed at the phantomjs@1.9.18 install script 'node install.js'.
    npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the phantomjs package,
    npm ERR! not with npm itself.
    npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
    npm ERR!     node install.js
    npm ERR! You can get their info via:
    npm ERR!     npm owner ls phantomjs
    npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
    npm ERR! error rolling back Error: EPERM, unlink 'C:\Users\mmcelhinney\pitch_v1\node_modules\phantomjs\lib\phantom\phantomjs.exe'
    npm ERR! error rolling back     at Error (native)
    npm ERR! error rolling back  { [Error: EPERM, unlink 'C:\Users\mmcelhinney\pitch_v1\node_modules\phantomjs\lib\phantom\phantomjs.exe']
    npm ERR! error rolling back   errno: -4048,
    npm ERR! error rolling back   code: 'EPERM',
    npm ERR! error rolling back   path: 'C:\\Users\\mmcelhinney\\pitch_v1\\node_modules\\phantomjs\\lib\\phantom\\phantomjs.exe' }
```

Excerpt from Debug log as well : 
            6379 info phantomjs@1.9.18 Failed to exec install script
            6380 verbose unlock done using            C:\Users\mmcelhinney\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_locks\phantomjs-69c2bf63828d859c.lock for C:\Users\mmcelhinney\pitch_v1\node_modules\phantomjs
            6381 verbose stack Error: phantomjs@1.9.18 install: `node install.js`
            6381 verbose stack Exit status 1
            6381 verbose stack     at EventEmitter. (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\lifecycle.js:213:16)
            6381 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:110:17)
            6381 verbose stack     at ChildProcess. (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\spawn.js:14:12)
            6381 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:110:17)
            6381 verbose stack     at maybeClose (child_process.js:1008:16)
            6381 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:1080:5)

Answer (score 0):

Try my solution here https://stackoverflow.com/a/35043377/5734480

It may be slightly different depending on your OS.